# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar todos los productos de una categoría, con Django?

Tags: python, django

Utilicé este modelo de Categoría recursivo para generar subcategorías vinculadas a una Categoría padre.

*Models.py*

```
class Categoria(models.Model):
    padre = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='hijos', on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='Categorias'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Producto(models.Model):
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, related_name='productos', on_delete=CASCADE)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=40,verbose_name="Nombre de Producto")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=1500,null=False,blank=True)
    precio = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/producto",null=False,blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.imagen.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url
```

En esta vista llamo a la categoría y sus productos

*views.py*

```
def detalleCategoria(request, slug):
    categoria = Categoria.objects.get(slug=slug)
    listado = categoria.productos.all()
    context ={
        'categoria': categoria,
        'productos': listado
    }
    return render(request, 'vistasTienda/detalleCategoria.html', context)
```

Todos los productos ingresados están vinculados a alguna subcategoría, lo cual de momento no me da problemas para mostrarlos en un template, sin embargo, lo que quiero conseguir es mostrar todos los productos correspondientes a una categoría padre, y esto no lo he logrado.

Ejemplo:

Categoría Padre: Mujer
SubCategorías: Zapatos Mujer, Pantalones Mujer, Poleras Mujer

Comment: lograste hacerlo, si todavía tienes el problema puedo ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Logre arreglarlo, es un poco tosco lo que cree, pero esta funcional

```
def detalleCategoria(request, slug):
    categoria = Categoria.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if (categoria.padre == None):
        subcat = Categoria.objects.filter(padre=categoria.id)
        listado = []
        for sc in subcat:
            productos = sc.productos.all()
            for pro in productos:
                item = {
                    'producto':{
                        'id': pro.id,
                        'nombre': pro.nombre,
                        'precio': pro.precio,
                        'imageURL': pro.imageURL,
                        'stock': pro.stock
                    }
                }
                listado.append(item)
            
    else:
        productos = categoria.productos.all()
        listado=[]
        for pro in productos:
                item = {
                    'producto':{
                        'id': pro.id,
                        'nombre': pro.nombre,
                        'precio': pro.precio,
                        'imageURL': pro.imageURL,
                        'stock': pro.stock
                    }
                }
                listado.append(item)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    try:
        paginator = Paginator(listado, 4)
        listado = paginator.page(page)
    except:
        raise Http404
    context ={
        'categoria': categoria,
        'entity': listado,
        'paginator': paginator
    }
    return render(request, 'vistasTienda/detalleCategoria.html', context)
```

Básicamente hago una validación para verificar si la categoría no tiene padre, y en base a eso traigo a sus subcategorías, luego con un ciclo for introduzco cada uno de los productos en una list que le paso al contexto.

Si alguien iba a ayudarme, con mucho gusto puedo escuchar su sugerencia, como dije anteriormente este código me resulto luego de muchos intentos y me quedo algo tosco a mi parecer.

**Lo del paginator lo introduje despues así que no es parte del problema**

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.